# Choosing between two companies: startup where I am an intern vs more stable company where I do not know my prospective colleagues

Tags: job-offer, new-job, japan

I am faced with a hard decision and I could really use the advice of a third independent party.

I have received a job offer from two companies and I have to give an answer before 2021 August 2 (Monday) at 17:00 JST. I would like you to give your honest opinion about which one you would choose if you were in my shoes. However, the answer should be useful to other people who might find themselves in a similar situation. It would be better if the answer were backed up by observations and experiences that you accumulated over the years.

Let me start by giving you a summary of how I got to this point. I am a last-year Ph.D. student at a Japanese University. I came here three years ago from Europe. My field of research is high-energy experimental Physics. I came to Japan because I like the Japanese language, culture, food, and society, even acknowledging its many quirks and contradictions ... but no country is perfect after all. I can speak reasonably fluent Japanese (otherwise I could have never found the following jobs).

During my Ph.D. I realized that I have no interest in an academic career. So I went through the meat grinder that is job hunting in Japan. It was tough but after many months I landed a job offer from 3 good companies. I count myself very lucky. I have already rejected one, but I am really torn between the following two companies that I will call A and B for privacy.

**Company A**

Startup company in the field of near-earth space exploitation

The good:

- The company is Japanese but almost half of the employers are foreigners.
- I have been doing an internship here for the last four months. It has been an extremely gratifying and fun experience. I really enjoyed the tasks assigned to me, which involved hardware and software R&D.
- I had contacts with about 10 people inside the company and every single one of them was nice, interesting, and had a very fascinating back-story and background.
- The position that I am applying to is well defined and I already know and love my direct superior because he is my internship mentor.
- I more or less know what kind of project I am going to work into and I like it.
- I like the company culture and believe in the company mission.
- There is a lot of freedom in the work style and even if it is a startup the working hours are not crazy.

The bad:

- No bonus
- The starting salary is not bad but it is not clear if and how much is going to increase.
- The company is growing and doing good but being a startup, its future is not so certain.
- The internal structure of the company is not very well defined and is still very fluid and dynamical.
- The office is not super bad but not super good either

**Company B**

Consulting company in the field of advanced software optimization.

The good:

- The money is good. Not insanely good but about 1.5 times better than company A.
- The company itself is much more stable. It is a Japanese company quoted on the Tokyo stock exchange market.
- The HR department has made it very very clear they want me in. They really tried their best to make me take the job.
- The company deals with many technologies I am interested in. Not everything seems like my cup of tea but I like being challenged so I am open about trying new stuff.
- The probability that I am going to be assigned to my first-choice department is very high (more than 80% they say).
- The office is magnificent (the building, the sight, the amenities, the cafeteria, etc...)
- The average overtime work hours are not so many at all. I think both companies have similar average overtime work hours (not many).

The bad:

- Even if the probability of being assigned to my first-choice department is high, still it is not 100%
- I have met briefly with the boss of my first-choice department and he seemed a very nice guy but I do not really know who I am going to work with, nor the specific project I am going to work into.

I really am at a loss because both companies seem very good. Each one I am going to choose is going to be a good choice ... nevertheless I want to give it as much thought as I can.

There is no real deal-breaker in either of the companies. My priorities are job content, work environment (mainly people), work conditions, and salary.

**I do not have any experience in the job market yet. I am wondering if there is any red flag that I cannot read? Or a green flag that I should give more weight?**

I particularly welcome an answer from people with long experience in similar fields.

Some additional info about me that might be relevant:

- I plan to stay in Japan for at least 5 years or more
- I have a Japanese girlfriend. Our relationship is still young but promising.
- I am in my early thirties. Not so young that I can afford many mistakes with my career anymore.
- I do not want to reveal the name of the involved companies. Please refrain from guessing.
- I might reveal my nationality and University in PM.

Comment: I would not trust the "80% chance assigned to my first-choice department" bit. Why not just tell you what department you're joining outright? I would read this as closer to 0%.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins I think that it is not possible for equity reasons for them to give me the guarantee that I am going to be assigned to the first-choice department. I am joining as a new grad and it would be unfair to the other new grads joining the company if I were given preferential treatment. They actually did not say that I have an 80% chance. They said that new grads expressing a preference are usually assigned to the preferred department 80~90% of the time. So I am inclined to trust them on these numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Congratulations, these both seem excellent options. You are in good shape.

The choice probably depends on your personal life goals and priorities, which you haven't talked about yet. If you primarily want to have fun and excitement, the startup looks like the better options. If career advancement and money are more important, than consulting seems the better choice.

Another angle to consider: if you are planning on having a family and children in the not too distant future, the more stable and predictable consulting gig seems a safer bet.

A few things to check:

1. Startups typically pay less but offer equity or some other "success based" compensation instead. Working for 50% less with no chance of potentially making it up could be a detractor.
2. Consultants are known to do A LOT of overtime and crunch work. I would doubly verify that this is NOT the case in company B (unless you are ok with it).

This is one of those things in life where you just have to make a decision and then never look back. I'm sure either option will be good and you will never know how the other option would have turned out.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback and for raising these two important issues. This is what I could understand by speaking with HR people at both companies. In the startup, there are some forms of success-based compensation and some prospects of career advancement but there is no clear structure and nothing is set in stone. When I asked for details about the future they replied "honestly we do not know". In the consulting company, the average overtime work hours is 13 hours a month. Even doubling this number, it would mean about one or two hours of (unpaid) overtime work a day.

Comment: Another naive question ... What do you mean by "equity"?

Comment: Equity: partial ownership of the company.  Could be stock options, actual shares, profit sharing, performance based bonus, etc. Startups often pay below market but there is a mechanism that pays off well when the startup takes off. So you bear some the risk but also benefit from its success if it works. Sometimes also called "deferred compensation" You get less now, but more later (if things go well) and that "more" needs to be significantly larger than the "less".

Answer (score 1):

You are 30+ years, have nearly done your Phd and are in a foreign country. You have a girl friend. That's great!

It's obviously now time to focus on job stability.

In most industries, if you don't rise up to management level or get assigned some management responsibilities by the time you are 35+, ageism will work against you as it is cheaper to hire younger people for the same work. This is especially true in the software industry. (Ofcourse, highly qualified or specialised skill workers do buck this trend, but it is not the norm).

In your place, I would only seriously consider the stable company over the startup you described, for the following reason:

1. You are a European in a Japanese corporate - that's a big advantage you already have over your future co-workers, especially if you will be working in a multi-national company. You will find that you will be given preferential treatment over others to interact with some of your company's foreign clients or if the company expands abroad. (As you mentioned consulting work, indeed, it is highly likely that's why they are so keen on you).
2. As you have already assessed, better and assured pay will give you more peace of mind than the future financial uncertainty of a startup.
3. The company's brand value will expose you to better job opportunities in the future in both Japan and abroad.
4. Asian parents really like it when a prospective groom works in a big, reputed companies with a stable income. ;)

I would consider the startup only keeping in mind two things:

1. You are absolutely sure what you want to work on, and that the startup will give you the opportunity to work on it and garner a LOT of experience and expertise in that area.
2. You are sure that particular experience and expertise will help you easily get a better paying job in another 3 years (by then, or if you are unlucky, before that, you may get a clear picture on the company's future and your role in it).

Answer (score 0):

If I was in your situation I would lean towards the startup mainly because it is more of a known quantity. Working with nice and smart people who you want to learn from is super important in a role.

Both the startup and big corporation have their risks. Consultancy firms can be volatile too. My experience in Western consulting firms is that you are the product and they add a brand to it before selling it to clients. If there is no demand, e.g. during a recession, they will fire you. Maybe the situation in Japan is different though.

In the case of startups, how easy would it be to find a job if it went under? In London, there are so many startups that you can easily jump to a different one. There's a lot of venture capital money right now and once funded companies all want the same group of people with experience in startups. So really the risks in joining a startup are low.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I think that the situation in Japan is a little different because firing an employee even with a strong reason is very difficult. Unless the company does not go bankrupt I would not consider being fired a real possibility.